# Is this C# code Redundant (WebImage ByteArray)

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, .net-7.0

I found this code in an old project for work and was wondering if this does anything.
Its in .net framework 4.8

Content contains an image as bytearray, set in constructor of the class.
in another function we check is content is not null and then create a WebImage object and then immediatly convert it to bytes again.

```
byte[] Content;
if (Content != null)
    Content = new WebImage(Content).GetBytes();
```

This code is pretty old and the person who wrote this is no longer with the company.

My Question now is, does this code anything? Isnt the bytearray the same before and after?
This is important because i have to migrate this project to .net 7 and the WebImage class is not available anymore.

Comment: Can't you simply compare the byte arrays before and after?

Comment: Is the returned byte array is same with the input?

Comment: It might do some basic optimizations by just loading the image (removing metadata for example) but as others have pointed out you should just compare the array before and after and see if it changes (and preferably becomes smaller).

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain this are code snippets. the content variable is set in the constructor and the conversion here happens some time later.

Comment: thanks for the answer ill try to run the code and compare the arrays before and after.

Comment: Image data has an ASCII header that indicates the image type and size.  So reading and writing is probably converting the image to a standard type.  For example you input could be bmp, jpg or tif and reading and writing the results will always be bmp.

Comment: the byte arrays are the same before and after. tested it with and without meta infos. so i guess this code does nothing. when we read and write the images we dont change image type or file ending.

Comment: Note that the constructor will probably throw an exception if the content does not actually represent an image, even if the documentation does not specify any exceptions. If this matters or not is up to you.